# System.err.println statements not getting printed on console after i launch my plugin in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am really finding it difficult to even frame this question. But i will try to explain this in detail.

I have created a plugin using gradle in Intellij Idea. What it does is, checks 2 json files and prints error, according to some logic. All is working well. As soon as i create a jar file of this plugin and do "install plugin from disk" in settings, and then launch plugin, it is not printing System.err.println statements on console, where i am in. Also i see is, idea log files is generating those print statements but not printing on console. Just wanted to know if someone has ever faced such issue, or can help me out. It would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your plugin does not have the access to input/output streams of the JVM process when you are executing it.

You can create a dialog/notification as per [this IntelliJ's guide](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/notifications.html?from=jetbrains.org#top-level-notifications-balloons)

OR

[This thread shows steps needed in creating your own text console](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206756385-How-to-make-a-simple-console-output).

HTH

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying to create my own text console. But not getting success in it. If you can share any of your code, that you might have worked upon it would be great. I am newbie to plugin development.